# Hide the Root Checkbox in a Kendo TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I know you can use checkbox template to control its look-and-feel but how would I hide the checkbox for the root node (and only the root node)?

**UPDATE**

The answer below does the trick as well. However, I ended up using a template like this:

```
checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true,
    template: "# if(item.Id != 1){# <input type='checkbox'  name='section[#= item.Id #]' value='true' />#} #"
}
```

"Id" is the id field in my dataSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do the trick but it is dirty, it's much nicer defining a template:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    ...
    checkboxes: true,
    dataBound : function () {
        $("#treeview > ul > li > div span.k-checkbox").hide();
    }
});
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/b3UBh/1/

Comment: note that this only works with local databinding. Other way is to hide nodes in css.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a class name by using HTMLAttributes

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "hideHeaderCheckbox" })
```

Then do something like this during document.ready

```
$("#idofyourtreeView .hideHeaderCheckbox").each(function () {
            $(this).find("div .k-checkbox input").eq(0).hide();
        });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found from this article of Telerik : https://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-treeview-checkboxes-on-parent-nodes

From the reference:

> The easiest approach is to hide checkboxes in root items with CSS:

```
<TelerikTreeView Class="root-checkboxes" />

<style>
    .root-checkboxes > ul > li > div:first-child .k-checkbox-wrapper > .k-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```